# Aggregate by date-time and compute a centroid as an output?

Tags: r, merge, centroids, aggregation

(I would prefer using R if possible)

I have a table with coordinates (in latitude, longitude), time information (YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS) and ID information (example provided). I sometimes have multiple coordinates in a one minute window for one ID. I would like to produce a table with continuous time (by="min") with:

- NA: if no coordinates are recorded at this particular time this particular ID.
- coordinate: if there is only one coordinate in the one minute window.
- centroid: if there are multiple coordinates

Example coordinate table:

```
Coordinates<-data.frame(GMT_Date= c("2017-04-16 15:15:00","2017-04-16 15:15:00","2017-04-16 15:15:00","2017-04-16 16:33:00","2017-04-16 16:33:00","2017-04-16 16:33:00","2017-04-16 16:33:00"),
                        Latitude= c(15.0,15.2,15.4,16.0,16.5,16.3,16.2),
                        Longitude= c(30.2,30.1,30.2,31.5,31.6,31.8,31.9),
                        ID= c("id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id1","id1"))
```

Example continuous time table:

```
startDate<-as.POSIXct("2017-04-16 00:01:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
endDate<-as.POSIXct("2017-05-23 23:59:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
time.table<-data.frame(GMT_date= seq(startDate,endDate,by="min"))
head(time.table)
```

Expected final output:

```
output.expected<-data.frame(GMT_date=c("2017-04-16 00:01:00","2017-04-16 15:15:00","2017-04-16 16:33:00"),
id1_centroid= c("NA","Latitude, Longitude", "Latitude, Longitude"),
id2_centroid=c("NA","NA","Latitude, Longitude"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial sketch using `aggregate`:

```
# Test table for raw coordinates
raw.coord<-data.frame(tm= c("2017-04-16 15:15:01","2017-04-16 15:15:02",
                        "2017-04-16 15:15:00",
                        "2017-04-16 16:33:00","2017-04-16 16:33:01",
                        "2017-04-16 16:33:02","2017-04-16 16:33:04"),
                  lat= c(15.0,15.2,15.4,16.0,16.5,16.3,16.2),
                  lon= c(30.2,30.1,30.2,31.5,31.6,31.8,NA),
                  id= c("id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id1","id1"))

# Create plain factors with minute granularity ..the merge key
raw.coord$ptm <- trunc(as.POSIXct(raw.coord$tm),unit="mins")

# Declare time factors for the aggregation ..should be improved
raw.coord$yr  <- (raw.coord$ptm)$year+1900
raw.coord$mo  <- (raw.coord$ptm)$mon+1
raw.coord$dy  <- (raw.coord$ptm)$mday
raw.coord$hr  <- (raw.coord$ptm)$hour
raw.coord$mn  <- (raw.coord$ptm)$min

# Aggregate positions with all time columns 
# for the choosen factors
avg.coord <- data.frame(
 tm  = unique(raw.coord$ptm),
 lat = aggregate(lat ~ yr+mo+dy+hr+mn, data = raw.coord, FUN=mean)$lat,
 lon = aggregate(lon ~ yr+mo+dy+hr+mn, data = raw.coord, FUN=mean)$lon
)
head(avg.coord)

# Construct the interval table with all timestamps between
# I change the interval because your setup produces 
# of too many NA's for an example 
sdt<-as.POSIXct("2017-04-16 15:14:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
edt<-as.POSIXct("2017-04-16 16:35:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
trj.coord <- data.frame(tm= seq(sdt,edt,by="min"))
trj.coord <- merge( trj.coord, avg.coord, by="tm", all=TRUE)

# Show the results
head(trj.coord)
tail(trj.coord)
```

Results

```
> head(trj.coord)
                   tm  lat      lon
1 2017-04-16 15:14:00   NA       NA
2 2017-04-16 15:15:00 15.2 30.16667
3 2017-04-16 15:16:00   NA       NA
4 2017-04-16 15:17:00   NA       NA
5 2017-04-16 15:18:00   NA       NA
6 2017-04-16 15:19:00   NA       NA
> tail(trj.coord)
                    tm   lat      lon
77 2017-04-16 16:30:00    NA       NA
78 2017-04-16 16:31:00    NA       NA
79 2017-04-16 16:32:00    NA       NA
80 2017-04-16 16:33:00 16.25 31.63333
81 2017-04-16 16:34:00    NA       NA
82 2017-04-16 16:35:00    NA       NA
```

I'm shure there is a R-way to avoid the expansion of the datetime fields `yr+mo+dy+hr+mn` and use the timestamps `tm` as a factor.

EDIT: To answer the ID context in the comment below, you cold bring in the ID with an non unique setup per minute into **one field**. I suggest to collect the and sort the ID's in this function:

```
# paste together the sorted qunique ID's 
punique<-function (id) { 
   return (paste(sort(unique(id)),collapse=' '))
};
```

The rest works like the other aggregations in the intermediate step for table `avg.coord`:

```
 id = aggregate(id ~ yr+mo+dy+hr+mn, data = raw.coord, FUN=punique)$id...
```

The other possibility is to treat the ID's as a factor in the aggregation:

```
 id = aggregate(id ~ yr+mo+dy+hr+mn+id, data = raw.coord, FUN=unique)$id...
```

but get an different granularity (addressing) you expected in your question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this solution. Do you have any idea how to add the ID as aggregation condition?

Comment: @Luc" I've add the ID comment  to the answer.